# how to get video file from blob url and upload that to youtube through javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, youtube-api, webrtc

how can i get video link or convert to file from blob URL created by recordRtc.

i have tried to get it from following code:

```
var fd = new FormData();
var filedata = document.getElementById("videourl").innerHTML;(this returns blob:link)
fd.append("video", filedata);
alert(fd.size);
```

but this is not converting it to file please help

Comment: I don't think it is possible to convert Blob-URI into Blob object. You need to be using `recordRTC.blob` property as mentioned here: http://recordrtc.org/RecordRTC.html#blob

Comment: `htmlVideoElement.mozCaptureStream` is supported only in Firefox.

Comment: thanx recordRTC.blob worked